# Why do you see colons while calling a javascript function in html sometimes?

Tags: javascript, html, function

A lot of the time I see people calling javascript functions using colon (:).

Like `onclick="javascript:functionname();"`

The same function works without `javascript:` and I'm curious to know when to use `javascript:` and when not to.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Colons are optional (but preferred) delimiters in JavaScript. `Any suggestions are appreciated.` don't ever do this, use [`.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener) once the page has loaded.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`javascript:` prefix is *extremely* important when you put code to anchor `href` attribute:

```
<a href="javascript:func();">Anchor</a>
```

Whereas in inline event attributes (like `onclick`, `onsubmit`, `onmouseover`, etc.) `javascript:` prefix is not important.

However, you should note that both approaches given here are not good to implement and you should use alternative ways (e.g as [@Paul S.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14605247/why-are-using-colon-while-calling-function-in-javascript/14605294#comment20391854_14605247) stated in the comments)

Answer (score 3):

This is not as commonly seen in `onclick` events as these events already execute javascript. You will may see something like the following quite a bit:

```
<a href="javascript: functionname(); return false;">Link</a>
```

The reason for such code is that by default an `href` attribute is trying to change the location or redirect. This tells the browser that the default `href` action will be javascript that is run. Otherwise, the function will not run and the page will refresh which is quite annoying.

Page refreshing is a common issue when using javascript like this in an anchor tag since an anchor tags default action is to refresh or load another page. The `return false;` at the end signals that the default action (i.e. refresh or load) should not fire.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the `javascript:` prefix is left over from when there were many other script types bouncing around on the web (vbScript, for example) and in order to differentiate between them in HTML you needed to provide these prefixes.

That being said, these tags do absolutely nothing in any browser other then IE anymore, and even in IE you generally can omit them.

Also notice that this entire question is moot since you should be binding event handlers through javascript, not in HTML.