# Can't open Excel from JScript embed inside an HTA

Tags: excel, com, jscript, hta

Following [this question](https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/k2isgi/documentation_examples_tutorials_for_excel_com/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3), I'm trying to convert the VBScript code on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/automate-excel-from-client-side-vbscript?source=docs) to JScript. If I runt the below `.hta` code:

```html
<HTML>
<BODY>
    <INPUT id=button1 name=button1 type=button value=Button>
    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">
        sub button1_onclick()
            dim app
            set app = createobject("Excel.Application")
            app.Visible = true
            dim wb
            set wb = app.workbooks.add
            end sub
    </SCRIPT>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

It opens an empty Excel sheet upon clicking on the button. as expected. However, if I convert the VBScript part to JScript

```html
<HTML>
<BODY>
    <INPUT id=button1 name=button1 type=button value=Button>
    <script LANGUAGE="JScript">
        function button1_onclick() {
            // var app = WScript.CreateObject("Excel.Application");
            var app = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
            app.Visible = true;
            var wb = app.Workbooks.Add();
        }
    </script>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

it doesn't open Excel at all when clicking the button. I would appreciate it if you could help me know what is the problem and how I can resolve it. Thanks for your support in advance.

Comment: `button1_onclick` function is never run. You need to attach an event listener to the input element, `<input onclick="openExcel();" ...>`, and change the function name to `openExcel` to avoid conflicts between element `id`s and global variables/functions.

Comment: Thanks @Teemu , have you tested this? because I did try it last night and it didn't work either. 

Comment: Yes, I have. If it still doesn't work for you, that's maybe because of the multiple languages used. If you've VBS and JS on the same page, you might need to point the correct language in the onclick attribute, like so: `<input onclick="javascript: openExcel();" ...>`. Your actual code in the event handler works as it is.

Comment: @Teemu No, I don't think that was the problem. I had commented the VBScript part out. I will test again tonight and will let you know here. thanks for your kind support. 

Comment: If you can't get it to work (check with an alert that the function is run), it might be something similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65103877/1169519), unfortunately I don't know the answer to that. Similar code to your's has been working in my HTA apps for a decade, even with the newest Office Excel.

Comment: A remediation to my second comment: "_If you've VBS and JS on the same page ..._" It's not just the code for the click event, it's any VBS on the page.

Comment: Also, the line commented out `WScript.CreateObject` will never work in an HTA because it doesn’t have access to the Windows Scripting Host. This is because MSHTA is it’s own host that supports Active Scripting languages. The caveat to this is you can still use some WScript libraries that are accessible through COM like `WScript.Shell` etc.

Comment: @Teemu figured the issue out. I was using the `onclick="<functionName>"` while I should have used `onclick="<functionName>()"`. See those parentheses apprantly matter.

Comment: I can imagine it's hard to move from VBS to JS, all gotchas are on the way ...

Comment: @Teemu well, actually I have zero experience with both. I rather learn the latter though. The issue is that there is much more documentation for VBScript than classic JScript.

Comment: Actually, I think you'll find you stumbled on that from the answer I have provided. @Teemu suggested including the event handler but my answer showed you how.

Comment: Also @Teemu the use of the language selection moniker in event handlers is inaccurate, it's been peddled so much now it's hard to separate fact from fiction. The sole purpose of language monikers like `vbscript:` and `javascript:` [are to bind functions directly from the `href` attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27253420/calling-vbscript-function-from-button-input-type#comment42982492_27253420). See [Why do you see colons while calling a javascript function in html sometimes?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14605294/692942).

Comment: @Lankymart Years ago (probably era of IE9), I answered a question (could have been in comments only) where OP said an inline eventlistener didn't run. I made some tests at that time, and I can remember that the issue was reproducible. The language first occurring in a file somehow "hijacked" the inline listeners, and "the language selection moniker" did solve that problem. I'd recall the event in the question was an onchange event of a select element. Unfortunately I couldn't find that post anymore, I even tried to find such a comment with a SEDE-query, but to no avail.

Comment: @Teemu that maybe a weird IE thing but language selection monikers where primarily designed to support launching code from a `href` any other usage is coincidental.

Comment: Using `onclick` element attribute to bind events is a poor approach anyway, the correct approach is to match the event syntax for JScript which in this case would be `function button1::onclick()`.

Comment: @Lankymart Isn't that syntax only for ActiveX events? I mean if we had an instance of IE as an ActiveX, then that would work. But now we have a DOM event, not an ActiveX event ..?

Comment: @Teemu not just for ActiveX controls, it's for JScript event binding as well. Go try it, both examples in my answer have been tested. To be clear the event binding comes from the Script Engine not from ActiveX. See [AutoMagic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/ms974564(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#automagic) - *"The good thing about this mechanism is you can use it to respond to ActiveX Control events."*.

Comment: @Lankymart I don't know what to say ... I've been working with HTAs for more than 15 years (mostly hobby-based, though), and I didn't know about the DOM event binding the Script engine can do. Thanks a lot for all this, every day is really for learning.

Comment: @Teemu I've been dipping out of VBScript and JScript for more years than I care to mention and still feel I'm learning new things. Sometimes, it's just so much time has passed that I'm refreshing what I once knew.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Why doesn't `Object_Event` syntax work?

It's actually very simple `Object_Event` syntax is VBScript, to allow events to automatically bind in JScript you just need to use the correct syntax which is `Object::Event`, here is an example using automatically bound events.

```html
<html>
<body>
    <input id="button1" name="button1" type="button" value="Button">
    <script language="JScript">
        function button1::onclick() {
            var app = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
            app.Visible = true;
            var wb = app.Workbooks.Add();
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Just tested this and it seems to be working, so it may just be you are missing the `onclick` event handler as [@Teemu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1169519/teemu) suggests [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65100113/cant-open-excel-from-jscript-embed-inside-an-hta#comment115096185_65100113).

```html
<html>
<body>
    <input id="button1" name="button1" type="button" value="Button" onclick="return button1_onclick();">
    <script language="JScript">
        function button1_onclick() {
            var app = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
            app.Visible = true;
            var wb = app.Workbooks.Add();
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The only real difference is the inclusion of the `onclick` event handler on the `<input>` element.

```html
onclick="return button1_onclick();"
```

It displays a button which when clicked opens Microsoft Excel with a new Workbook.

---

#### Useful Links

- [Javascript in HTA File](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3158322/692942)
- [Open programs from HTA application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58271074/692942)
- [ActiveX event handlers in an HTA using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41888383/692942)
   *(the fact this is called Javascript just shows the misinformation around JScript)*.
- [MSDN (Scripting Clinic) - Scripting Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/ms974564(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)